# Exponential Moving Average with different kernels

Tags: c#, python, math, statistics, smoothing

I am trying to replicate some formulas but am having trouble translating the math to code.

Here is the simple Exponential Moving Average
[image: Exponential Moving Average]

In c#:

```
out[1] = values[1];
for (i in 2:N(X)) {
  tmp = (times[i] - times[i-1]) / tau;
  w = exp(-tmp);
  w2 = (1 - w) / tmp;
  out[i] = out[i-1] * w + values[i] * (1 - w2) + values[i-1] * (w2 - w);
}
```

In Python:

```
mu = numpy.exp ((ts[1] - ts[0]) / self.tau)
nu = 1.0 - mu
return numpy.array ([
mu * el + nu * arr[0] for el, arr in zip (last, arrays)
])
```

I want to be able to specify different kernels and am not sure how to go about it as described here:
[image: EMA kernel]
[image: MA]
This is all done so I can eventually recreate this moving differential given here:
[image]

Thanks for any help given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach here is to have a method that returns the kernel.

From what I am able to see, inputs to this method would be `kerneltype`, `i`, and `otherInputs`.

A simple approach would be:

```
for(int i = 1; i < values.length(); i++)
{
    tmp = (times[i] - times[i-1]) / tau;
    //w = exp(-tmp);
    //w2 = (1 - w) / tmp;
    List<Object> kernelInputsInital = new List<Object>();
    kernelInputsInitial.Add(tmp);  //takes in the first argument
    kernelInputsInitial.Add(true); //expected to calculate the first
    w = GetKernel(KernelType.Exponential, i, kernelInputsInitial);

    List<Object> kernelInputsSecondTerm = new List<Object>();
    kernelInputsSecondTerm.Add(w);  //takes in the first argument
    kernelInputsSecondTerm.Add(false); //expected to calculate the first
    w2 = GetKernel(KernelType.Exponential, i, kernelInputsInitial);

    out[i] = out[i-1] * w + values[i] * (1 - w2) + values[i-1] * (w2 - w);
    ....
}
```

This is of course terribly, terribly rough, and a *lot* of improvement can be made, but it is intended to merely get the point across.

I would use an interface to represent a kernel, and have classes derived per kernel. In my experience, that produces sufficiently readable and maintainable code, but there's always room for improvement.